# Test Case Application

Tags: open-source, software-testing, desktop-client

I am looking for a (preferably free) Test Case application where I can do the following:

- Write Test Cases
- Organize Test Cases into Suites or Groups of Tests or whatever

I do not need:

- Integration
- Bug Reporting
- Test Execution

I just need something simple and downloadable.

I am looking for something that I can house on my machine because I want my test cases to be secure, private.

I don't want a system that plugs into something else because this would only be used by me and not a team of people, but it would be nice to be able to export in a common file format

Any OS should be fine: I work mostly on Windows and can see myself working on Linux too.

---

I am looking for a standalone application that doesn't *require* another application to run or edit tests.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to write test cases, and then not execute them? Are these prose test cases, or are they made of source code?

Comment: I am looking for something to organize manual tests, I would have to say yes to Prose Test Cases.  I was writing High Level test cases and wanted to be more organized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Step-by-step manual system test](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24725/step-by-step-manual-system-test)

Comment: I disagree @Alejandro, that request is quite different than my request.